# What is the alternative to the 2-way ANOVA when the data are non-parametric in addition to being non-ordinal

Tags: anova, nonparametric, manova

I understand that the scheirer-ray-hare test would be a good option, however, the literature mentions that it is not reliable in my case because it uses data on an ordinal scale. What alternative could I make if my dependent variable is quanti-continuous and I have 3 groups of independent variables and each one had 2 subgroups? Also I'm using STATA

EDIT: My dependant variable is the enzymatic activity of microbial enzymes in the soil, and I want to perform an anova to determine whether or not there is interaction with the factors of land use, the type of vegetation and depth, but as you will notice, I have a quantitative variable and the independent ones that are nominal. In addition to this, according to the Shapiro Wilk normality analysis and the homogeneity of variances, my data are non-parametric, so I could not opt ​​for an Anova and also I can´t use Fisher because I dont have ordinal data.

Comment: This seems impossibly generic. How about explaining your particular data and what you want to know from them?

Comment: Sure, my dependant variable is the enzymatic activity of microbial enzymes in the soil, and I want to perform an anova to determine whether or not there is interaction with the factors of land use, the type of vegetation and depth, but as you will notice, I have a quantitative variable and the independent ones that are nominal. In addition to this, according to the Shapiro Wilk normality analysis and the homogeneity of variances, my data are non-parametric, so I could not opt ​​for an Anova and also I can´t use Fisher because I dont have ordinal data.

Comment: Any reason that you can't rank transform the dependent variable? ANOVA on ranks is a fairly straight forward non-parametric approach. Also, normality of the DV is not an assumption of the ANOVA, so S-W doesn't rule out an ANOVA. Since you can run an ANOVA as a linear regression, you're more interested in the normality of the residuals, which isn't always detectable in the raw distribution. For unequal variances, you can also just choose post hocs that allow for that (like Games-Howell)

Comment: Billy thanks for the answer, this really helps my study, I did not take the transformation data because after doing it there are still no parametrics, but I will try with your tips, thanks again :)